# Strncpy для файла

Tags: строки, c++

есть файл 1.txt с текстом.
как скопировать от i до j из текста в строку и вывести на экран?
есть ли аналогии strncpy

Comment: Что означает «от `i` до `j`»? Вы о символах или о строках?

Comment: @VladD 
номер символа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void fncpy(int iMin, int iMax)
{
    string strBuff;
    ifstream fin ("1.txt");

    int i = 0;

    while (iMin > 0)
    {
        getline(fin, strBuff);
        iMin--;
        i++;
    }

    for(; i <= iMax; i++)
    {
        getline(fin, strBuff);
        cout << strBuff << endl;
    }

    fin.close();
}

int main(void)
{
    int iMinLine, iMaxLine;
    cin >> iMinLine >> iMaxLine;
    fncpy(iMinLine, iMaxLine);

    return 0;
}
```